# Credit card payment form, enable scanning in Chrome with Angular & Kendo UI?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, kendo-ui, credit-card, scanning

I am working on a credit card payment form in Angular with Kendo UI. I want to enable scanning (which is, weirdly, part of browser autocomplete functionality).

I have read [this article](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/autofill-what-web-devs-should-know-but-dont/), and experimented with [this basic example](https://codepen.io/tommyno/pen/vgLYKY?editors=1100)
and [this workaround for my specific case](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-star-66gbkb?file=/src/app/app.component.ts):

`

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("creditCardNumber") creditCardNumber;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.creditCardNumber.input.nativeElement.setAttribute(
      "autocomplete",
      "cc-number"
    );
  }
}
```

`

No luck - the autocomplete attributes are added to my kendo elements, but the scanner still does not work.
I've tried using ngrok, so it doesn't appear to be an https issue.

I tried reverse engineering the form - scanning works in chrome with the raw html, but stops working when I introduce Angular.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm starting to lose my mind.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not in a position to test this because I do not have a scanner, but if you want the kendo appearance with the autocomplete functionality why don't you use TextBox directive ([documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/textbox/textbox-directive/)) and set the autocomplete on the input. Something like this:

```html
<input #creditCardNumber autocomplete="cc-number" kendoTextBox />
```

Fiddle: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-bird-98jmp0?file=/src/app/app.component.ts